# Bring another form to front

Tags: c#

How can I bring another form to front. Like I'm working on Form2 and I want to bring Form1 to front? I've tried this:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.BringToFront();
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Does `frm1.Show(); frm1.BringToFront();` work?

Answer (score 0):

If the form is already opened in the background, you need to find it first and then bring it to the front.

What you are doing is to create a *new* instance of it. It will surely not work.

try this:

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault()?.BringToFront();
```

Or try with `Activate`

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault()?.Activate();
```